# How to update the user profile

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, user-input

When my user signs into the user profile the username is default it remains at “username” instead of the custom username that user
sign up with from firebase database.  How do you fix this code to upload the username from firebase database?

```
let displayName = displayNameText.text
        DatabaseRef = Database.database().reference()
            let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = displayName
            changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
              // ...
            }
            if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
                DatabaseRef.child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    let dictionary = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let username = dictionary?["username"] as? String ?? "username"
                    self.displayNameText.text = username
```

Comment: Did you look at the firebase console and verify that the username is indeed getting save how you expect?

Comment: Yes It’s Saved Correctly @DrewG23

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the `let username` line and print out what dictionary is?

Comment: Try to print value of dictionary and check key name is proper for username

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing here. The first section of code is updating the users *firebase profile* with a display name and that code is unrelated the second section where a */users/uid/username* node is being read. Can you clarify the question?